# Update a bot variable with user input created in boot framework

Tags: botframework, power-virtual-agents

I created in bot composer a new multiple choice for a user to select, given the user answer i want to update or set the value of a variable created in Power Virtual Agents.

How can i set the value of a bot variable within the bot framework composer?

The dialog in frame composer

[image]

The variable I want to set

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relevant this is, or whether the situation over there has made this irrelevant altogether, however.

This can be done using global variables:
[How to access Bot Framework Composer dialog variables in PVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057135/how-to-access-bot-framework-composer-dialog-variables-in-pva)

Essentially just set the variable that you have in PVA to be accessible by doing this:
**PVA Usage Options**

[image]

Give it a memorable name, and then pull it to Bot Framework Composer.

To pass variables back.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Bot-Extensibility/Pass-variable-from-Bot-Framework-back-to-PVA/td-p/1386597

Hope this helps, good luck, and stay strong!